# Function to fit experimental data ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, data-analysis

I am trying to construct a simple ODE system model for experimental data describing yeast's growth and its glucose consumption. So far my attempt is the following:

$\frac{dG}{dt} =-v_1\\
\frac{dY}{dt} =v_1-v_2\\
v_1= \frac{k_1\,.\,Y\,.\,G}{1+k_2\,.\,G}\\
v_2= k_3\,.\,Y\\$

I have no knowledge about my three kinetic constants $k$, so I am trying at the same time to estimate them through fitting my system to experimental data.

So far, my fit looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypIwx.png) (in my graph the M stands for G)

My question is, if someone could advise me what kind of function should I try out in order to avoid that the decrease of yeast reach values so near to zero?

I was thinking about a piecewise function; however, I have no idea if that could be a good solution, or there is a way to do it through a continuous one.

In case that could be worth to know, I am estimating the unknown constants with Pyomo for Python.

*** EDIT 08.08.2016: ***
My data is time(hours), glucose(mg/L) and yeast (mg/L)

```
time    glucose yeast
0   94.4    3.43
4   83.5    4.83
8   72.2    6.13
12  61.2    7.06
16  50.6    7.84
20  41.4    8.19
24  33.5    8.05
28  26.8    6.94
32  20.9    5.44
36  15.6    4.43
40  11.6    3.96
44  8.63    3.75
48  6.171   3.61
52  4.473   3.55
56  3.069   3.49
60  2.309   3.4
64  1.608   3.33
68  1.199   3.28
72  1.025   3.21
76  0.9097  3.14
80  0.8527  3.09
84  0.7957  3.02
88  0.6802  2.95
92  0.5647  2.9
96  0.4491  2.86
100 0.3336  2.79
104 0   2.74
108 0   2.69
112 0   2.64
116 0   2.6
120 0   2.55
124 0   2.5
128 0   2.45
132 0   2.41
136 0   2.36
140 0   2.31
144 0   2.27
```

Comment: Look up inverse problems in ODEs. I suggest this rather than simply giving you an answer because this is inevitably an overdetermined problem. Choosing the right "answer" to an overdetermined problem generally requires some amount of input from the model rather than having a purely mathematical answer. Rather, the model says how we measure the "goodness" of an answer and then the math tells you how to find the best one relative to that measure of "goodness".

Comment: The underlying problem may be one of inconsistency between measurement technique and the model.  The model predicts yeast "growth" that amounts to exponential die-off after the population peaks, where your measurements reflect a decline in yeast that is slower.  To borrow a line from [Princess Bride](https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/princess_bride/quotes/), perhaps the reality is that the yeast are "only mostly dead".

Comment: @ Mau : I think that it is possible to compute the approximates of $k_1$ , $k_2$ , $k_3$ with the method explained in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales . You problem is unusual. It isn't treated in the referenced paper, but it seems not complicated to treat it. If you post the data (instead of the graph), I could test the convenience and accuracy of this special method of regression in the case of your problem.

Comment: @JJacquelin thank you very much for your interest, I just added the data and I will start reading your paper (at least as far as I can since I do not know French)

Comment: @Mau. Reading this paper will not give you the answer to your question because the case of system of differential equations isn't treated. Before that, see my answer which point out a preliminary problem. When this problem will be overcome, it will be possible to adapt the general method shown in the paper to the case of two differential equations. This is very simple and a straightforward procedure of computation will be available to compute the adjusted parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my tests it seems that the experimental data is inconsistent with the system of differential equations :
$$\begin{cases}
\frac{dG}{dt} =-v_1\\
\frac{dY}{dt} =v_1-v_2\\
v_1= \frac{k_1\,.\,Y\,.\,G}{1+k_2\,.\,G}\\
v_2= k_3\,.\,Y\\
\end{cases}$$
Is there not a typo ? Are you sure that these differential equations are a correct model for the physical experiment ?

For example, among other tests :
$$\frac{v_2}{Y}=-\frac{\frac{dG}{dt}+\frac{dY}{dt}}{Y}$$
The drawing should show approximately an horizontal line, since $\frac{v_2}{Y}=k_3$

It is far to be true (figure below). I cannot say where is the mistake.

I think that this inconsistency is the main cause of your difficulty to make the curve issued from the system of equations to fit with the experimental data.

[image]

In preliminary tests, one can use only simple approximates, such as :
$$\left(\frac{dG}{dt}\right)_k\simeq \frac{G_{k+1}-G_{k-1}}{t_{k+1}-t_{k-1}}$$ 
$$\left(\frac{dY}{dt}\right)_k\simeq \frac{Y_{k+1}-Y_{k-1}}{t_{k+1}-t_{k-1}}$$
For each point, the sum gives an approximate of $v_2$, then of $-\frac{v_2}{Y}$

.

PROCEDURE for computing approximates of $k_1$ , $k_2$ , $k_3$ :

[image]

For information, the integral equations used are :
$$\begin{cases}
G(t)=-\frac{k_2}{2}\left(G(t)\right)^2-k_1\int G(t)Y(t)dt \\
G(t)+Y(t)=k_3\int Y(t)dt
\end{cases}$$
This system of integral equations comes from the integration of the above system of differential equations.
The general principle of the method is presented in the paper : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales
.

NUMERICAL EXAMPLE :
[image]

The goal is ( for an example of exact values $k_1$ , $k_2$ , $k_3$ ) to compare to the results $k_1$ , $k_2$ , $k_3$ obtained with the above procedure of computation.

So, it is necessary to chose an arbitrary example of values $k_1$ , $k_2$ , $k_3$ , together with initial values $G(t_1)$ and $Y(t_1)$, for example $G(0)=80$ , $Y(0)=4$.

Then, the system of ODEs is numerically solved and the values $G(t_k)$ and $Y(t_k)$ are recorded along the computation. These values are rounded. They are shown on the above figure.

From this data, the procedure of regression leads to the computed values of $G(t_k)$ and $Y(t_k)$ shown on the figure.

Comment: thanks again for your effort, answering your question, I am trying to figure out a proper ODE system for explaining the data, so the equations that I gave were my first guesses. About your test for inconsistency, might you explain me a little bit more?. Regarding your paper, I was wondering if it could be implemented in a more complex ODE system? (let's say more than 5 ODEs) and how many unknown parameters could deal with? thanks in advance

Comment: In addition to my first answer, see the equations to compute approximates of the derivatives, directly from the experimental data. Then, it is possible to test if the parameters involved in the differential equations are roughly constant or not.

Comment: As explained in the paper, using numerical calculus of derivatives is generally not robust, nor accurate. Of course, they can be used for preliminary tests. But instead of, integral equations are recommended. I cannot anser to your question about more complex system of ODEs without specific studies. It is too early before knowing if it works in the present simple case. In case of two differential equations of the kind considered, I made a few simulations and it works very well.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation. Just a final question, for the equation of $\frac{v_2}{Y}$ the second term on the numerator should be $\frac{dY}{dt}$ ? I mean $\frac{v_2}{Y} = - \frac{\frac{dG}{dt}+\frac{dY}{dt}}{Y}$

Comment: Of course!  A typo. Now corrected.

Comment: A numerical example is added to the main answer.